# Setting up preview of Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

The Yii2 preview was recently released and is available on [github](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2). I want to take it for a test drive, but the "documentation" so far gets outdated almost instantly since it is still under heavy development. I have tried to follow [this guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/490/creating-a-simple-crud-app-with-yii2/) on creating a simple CRUD app with Yii2, but it fails at the step:

```
php yiic.php app/create /var/www/yii2
```

With the error:

```
Could not open input file: yiic.php
```

Indicating that there is no file called `yiic.php`. The only folder within the framework folder is yii (`framework/yii`), and within that folder there is no file `yiic.php`, only `Yii.php` which when called in the command line gives the command list:

```
The following commands are available:
- asset
- cache
- help
- message
- migrate
```

Anyone managed to successfully setup a Yii2 app? Care to share how you got it done?

Comment: It seems to be simply a path error, make sure you are in the framework folder or just specify it in your command

Comment: I've tried creating an app with a fresh download of Yii2 and the results are the same. Someone deleted/moved Yiic perhaps?

Comment: seems like yiic has been removed, lots of discussion happening in github, some important links: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/77#issuecomment-17442062, more links: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/490/creating-a-simple-crud-app-with-yii2/#c13322, EDIT: for now it seems the app/ directory can be copied, according to : https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/108#issuecomment-17449930

Comment: http://freetuts.org/tutorial/4?title=Installing+Yii2+framework+on+Ubuntu+14.04 Here you can find full tutorial on how to install yii2 basic and advanced applications.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Seems like yiic has been removed for now, there are alternatives though, so read on.

It's all in the early stages, so the following method could break in the coming days/weeks/months. Therefore use with caution.

There are 2 ways to do this now:

1. Use [composer](http://getcomposer.org/). (I recommend this option.)
2. Directly copy the contents of *yii2/apps/* directory to your apps directory, depending on the type of app you want to try.

---

There are currently 2 options for type of app - advanced, and basic. Both are in their respective directories within the yii2/apps/ directory, i.e *yii2/apps/advanced* and *yii2/apps/basic*.

---

For basic go through the [basic readme.md](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/apps/basic/README.md), and for advanced go through the [advanced readme.md](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/apps/advanced/README.md).

---

1. The directions for using composer are given in the respective readme.md files. Including them here for completeness:

   - Basic app:

     1. Install composer, if you don't have it.
     2. Use composer to install the app alongwith dependencies(Yii):
        `php path/to/composer.phar create-project --stability=dev yiisoft/yii2-app-basic my_yii2_trial`
     3. Access app from `http://localhost/my_yii2_trial/www`
   - Advanced app:

     1. Install composer, if you don't have it.
     2. Use composer to install the app alongwith dependencies(Yii):
        `php path/to/composer.phar create-project --stability=dev yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced my_yii2_trial`
     3. According to readme, after step 2 app should be accessible, but composer was failing(see [issue 439](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/439)). With [schmunk's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/291573/schmunk) tip, ran the *install* or *install.bat* command that gets copied by composer: `./install` . Selected development environment (by entering choice `0` in the instructions that show up when running `install` command). 
        **Update:** The command has been renamed to `init`, composer doesn't fail anymore, with fix from Qiang (check the [issue 439](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/439) for more details).
     4. Access app at: `http://localhost/my_yii2_trial/frontend/www` or `http://localhost/my_yii2_trial/backstage/www`
2. Here's how to copy the directory and get it working:

   - Basic app:

     1. **create** your web-accessible directory for the app : *my_yii2_trial*
     2. **copy all** files and folders from *yii2/apps/basic/* directory to *my_yii2_trial/* directory.
     3. **modify** the *my_yii2_trial/www/index.php* file to point to the correct path for Yii.php.
        For me it was within *yii2/framework/yii/*
     4. **comment** the line that tries to include *../vendor/autoload.php* file, I couldn't find that file anywhere, <strike>so its probably for some future use.</strike> it is the autoloader provided by composer.
     5. **Access** from browser : `http://localhost/my_yii2_trial/www`
   - Advanced app:

     1. **create** your web-accessible directory for the app : *my_yii2_trial*
     2. **copy all** files and folders from *yii2/apps/advanced/* directory to *my_yii2_trial/* directory.
     3. **modify** the *my_yii2_trial/frontend/www/index.php* file to point to the correct path for Yii.php. Similarly modify *backstage/www/index.php*.
     4. **comment** the line that tries to include *../vendor/autoload.php* file in both the *index.php* of *backstage* and *frontend*.
     5. **Access** app at: `http://localhost/my_yii2_trial/frontend/www` or `http://localhost/my_yii2_trial/backstage/www`

---

Some important links to read more about this: [issue 77](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/77), [issue 108](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/108), [issue 131](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/131), and [wiki comment](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/490/creating-a-simple-crud-app-with-yii2/#c13322).

---

I am not sure how composer's autoloader is being used, so can't comment on that. Also in future versions, *backstage* might be renamed to *backend*.

Comment: Updated answer, more complete now.

Comment: i am getting an error like this, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in D:\xampp\htdocs\my_yii2_trial\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\yii\Yii.php on line 25

Comment: @mazraara, i have seen your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741466/installing-yii-2-demo-application), and added an answer there.

Comment: after installing the advanced example I was getting errors that there was no database so I created the database yii2advanced (user root no password) and then went to the root of the project and ran yii migrate  which populated the database with the needed tables

Comment: I've tried to install by copying the directory, but it is giving an error: ...vendor/yiisoft/extensions.php): failed to open stream. coudln't find extensions.php from any directory, and I commented this line, but it's giving more errors. What is the problem do you think?

Comment: @SarvarNishonboyev which app(basic or advanced?) did u try to install? and from where did you download? did you also try installing with composer? I can try and tell you the exact solution only when u answer these questions.

Comment: @bool.dev I've succeeded installing by composer. But couldn't fix the problem by copying files, it's just headache. better to install by composer. Thanks.

Comment: i m getting error in run the composer.phar file please tell me how to run php path/to/composer.phar create-project --stability=dev yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced my_yii2_trial command in my ubuntu

Comment: @GauravParashar please ask a separate question with the exact error, the steps above are correct, your issue is somewhere else, hence i ask you to ask a new question.

Comment: @bool.dev thanks for your reply ,Actually i am new here so i posted some wrong questions so i am banned to post questions for some days.

Comment: @GauravParashar, that's ok, try to read the advanced readme.md link, provided in answer. maybe you missed a step.