# Installing Yii 2 demo application

Tags: php, yii, yii2

i am trying to install yii 2 and to run the basic or advanced application.

i have tried the steps given here [Setting up preview of Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788169/setting-up-preview-of-yii2/16790093#16790093) to do this.

the steps i followed,

```
1 - Installed the composer
2 - Use composer to install the app alongwith dependencies(Yii): php path/to/composer.phar create-project --stability=dev yiisoft/yii2-app-basic my_yii2_trial
3 - Access app from http://localhost/my_yii2_trial/web
```

The problem is, i am getting this syntax error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in D:\xampp\htdocs\my_yii2_trial\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\yii\Yii.php on line 25
```

can any body help to resolver this issue pls

Comment: I think latest release of yii is 1.1.14 , where did you get number 2?

Comment: @tinyByte here is where i got it from https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2 its the latest one and its not yet ready to production. its under public preview. any idea how can i resolve this ?

Comment: that is not ready for production yet, why would you want to put your time and effort in that? that release may or may not change significantly without prior notice release

Comment: @tinyByte ok. the issue here was i havent installed php 5.4. now it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yii2 has started using [PHP 5.4's Short array syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). Your error creeps up because of:

```
spl_autoload_register(['Yii', 'autoload'], true, true);
```

in [Yii.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/yii/Yii.php#L25), which is the new short array syntax. As you have already figured out, you need to install PHP 5.4 now to run Yii2 apps.

---

[The commit which made the changes to short array syntax.](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/commit/1f6a8230732d829cdf2f3ca6755e4ac32f2c6f4f)

[The docs and composer details that have been changed.](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/commit/e115b0c8604a498adde9604ab250e24487045ec5)

[The discussion where the decision to move to PHP 5.4 was made.](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/35)

---

As Yii2 is still in heavy development, its requirements are also changing. So be sure to read the readme thoroughly before installing.

---

See also the [Backward Incompatible changes list for PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php), to make changes to your existing code.

Comment: can anyone tell me please how to install yii2 on ubuntu with proper steps please and thanks in advance

Comment: @GauravParashar please ask a separate question, this question is only about syntax error after installing.

Answer (score 5):

Install PHP 5.4 to resolve this issue.

Comment: Simple answer sometimes better :)

Answer (score 1):

**Yii2 Installation Following command:**

**(1) First install Composer (LINUX):**

**Locally:**

*curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php*

**OR**

**(1) First install Composer (WINDOWS):**

*C:\Users\username>cd C:\bin*

*C:\bin>php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php*

**Note:** If the above fails due to readfile, use the http url or enable php_openssl.dll in php.ini

*C:\bin>echo @php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*>composer.bat*

*C:\Users\username>composer -V*

*Composer version 27d8904*

---

**(2) Yii2 framework online downloads:**

**Basic App:**

*php composer.phar create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic 2.0.0-beta*

**Advanced App:**

*php composer.phar create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced advanced 2.0.0-beta*

---

**(3) Other App Settings Command:**

*php init*

*php yii migrate*

Answer (score 0):

**Here is command lines to install yii2 on ubuntu:**

cd /var/www

/var/www$ ls

/var/www$ cd myyii2

/var/www/myyii2$ ls

/var/www/myyii2$ ls -al

/var/www/myyii2$ ls

/var/www/myyii2$ php init

**/* Your choice [0-1, or "q" to quit] 0*/**

**choose 0  for developemnt and type yes**

php yii migrate (/var/www/myyii2$ php yii migrate)

**Before this command need to download advance setup like [yii-advanced-app-2.0.7.tgz]**